# Add class to div if another div (created by Wordpress shortcode) exists

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, shortcode

I've tried (and searched) many versions of what I want to do, and I can't work it out.

I'm building on a Wordpress theme where the author will enter something in a shortcode (so they have the ability to easily change the color using the Visual Editor toolbar) but not for every post.

I have set the shortcode up (named .tag) which works.

However, I want the tag to appear **in front** of the post title (.post-title) and push it over to the right (75px), **if** the tag is included in the post. If it isn't, I want the post title to stay where it is.

I think I need something like this: [Jquery check if element exists then add class to different element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734757/jquery-check-if-element-exists-then-add-class-to-different-element)

but I can't get this to work for my needs!

Is my issue that it can't check if the tag is included (as it is in the post body which comes after the post title) and then move it?

Any advice would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is something you'll want to do server-side rather than with javascript. Try `has_shortcode()`:

```
global $post;
if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'tag')) {
  echo '<h1 class="post-title has-shortcode">Title</h1>';
} else {
  echo '<h1 class="post-title">Title</h1>';
}
```

You'll probably want to add this as a filter on `the_title`?

(codex documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode))

Comment: Thanks loop_duplicate, this led me in the direction of: http://digitalraindrops.net/2011/09/wordpress-code-series-if-then-else/ - the code that finally worked was (ignore the inline styling! :): 
    `<?php if(has_shortcode($post->post_content, 'tag')) : ?>
   <div class="post-title" style="margin-left: 85px;"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
<?php else : ?>
   <div class="post-title"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer helped solve your question, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

without the html I can't be sure but u could simply use a css pseudo class like :parent to get that behavior without jquery events involved.

check this out

[css_pseudo_classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
.tag:parent {
    whatever:whatever;
}
```

Comment: the `:parent` selector you mention doesn't exist for CSS

Comment: Don't trust w3schools, they're bad.